# How can i send UUID object as parameter in HTTP Request Body data?

Tags: jmeter

I have **UUID** value converted from String:

```
String SessionUUID1= "8B6FA50D-59D0-4582-9396-C4A376EBBC7E";
UUID finaluid = UUID.fromString(SessionUUID1.toString());
```

but unable to assign it to **Jmeter** variable and also unable to pass it as Json data in body data.

I should assign finaluid as json data to send the request.

Iam using Beanshell Preprocessor to populate the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [vars.putObject](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method to store non-String variable value like:

```
vars.putObject("finaluid", finaluid);
```

Not sure what do you mean by `I should assign finaluid as json data`, if you sending JSON via [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler - it won't accept UUID, you'll have to convert it back to string.

Check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for some Beanshell examples and explanation of pre-defined variables.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, Yes i am trying to send the UUID in Body data as Json for HTTP Request Sampler. It is not accepting UUID, Only accepts string values. Thank you so much for the clarification.